# Does a discriminant condition on $f(x,y)$ imply that $f$ is weighted homogeneous?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, discriminant, toric-varieties

[I cross-posted this question as https://mathoverflow.net/questions/431454. (That version is also slightly updated.)]

Let $f = \sum_{i=m}^n f_iy^i \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ be a polynomial (where $f_i \in \mathbb{C}[x]$ with $f_m,f_n \ne 0$ and $n > m$), and let $\operatorname{Disc}_y(x) \in \mathbb{C}[x]$ be the discriminant of $f$ with respect to $y$ (i.e., for every $a \in \mathbb{C}$, $\operatorname{Disc}_y(a)$ is the discriminant of $f(a,y)$). I got the impression that $f$ is weighted homogeneous (with possibly negative weights) if and only if the following three conditions hold:

1. $f_m$ is a (non-zero) monomial in $x$
2. $f_n$ is a (non-zero) monomial in $x$
3. $\operatorname{Disc}_y$ is a non-zero monomial in $x$

The direction "$\Rightarrow$" should not be too hard to prove: 1 and 2 are clear, and I think that 3 follows from the formula expressing the discriminant in terms of the coefficients of a polynomial. My question is: Is "$\Leftarrow$" also true? This seems more surprising, given that it yields strong conditions on $f$; since the question seems rather elementary, I am hoping that this might be known.

Some thoughts/remarks (which didn't yield a solution yet):

- If one thinks of $f$ as defining a variety $V \subset \mathbb{C}^\times \times \mathbb{P}^1\mathbb{C}$, then 1 and 2 say that $V \subset \mathbb{C}^\times \times \mathbb{C}^\times$, and 3 says that the projection to the first coordinate is unramified.
- Consider $g := y \cdot \partial f/\partial y$. It is not hard to verify that 1, 2 and 3 together are equivalent to: the subvarieties of $\mathbb{C}^\times \times \mathbb{P}^1\mathbb{C}$ defined by $f$ and $g$ have empty intersection. Applying a version of Bezout's Theorem for subvarieties of $\mathbb{P}^1\mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{P}^1\mathbb{C}$ thus yields a lot of intersections above $0$ and $\infty$.
- If $n$ (the degree in $y$) is 2, then one can easily prove the claim using the formula for the discriminant. I was also able to prove the claim when $f$ consists of only three monomials.

Comment: Not in general. If $f$ has a multiple root with respect to $y$, you can get all of your conditions to be satisfied but fail to have a weighted homogeneous polynomial. For instance, $y^2+(x+x^2)y^3+y^4$ fulfills all of your conditions but is not weighted homogeneous.

Comment: @KReiser: Thanks for this. It turns out that I wasn't precise enough: instead of writing "monomial in $x$", I should have written "non-zero monomial in $x$" or something like that (in all three conditions). I will edit it accordingly. (I'll have to think about the right formulation to get an "if and only if", but in reality, I'm only interested in $\Leftarrow$.)

Comment: I did the editing. (In particular, instead of $f_0$ being a monomial, I should impose that the lowest degree in $y$ part should be a monomial in $x$.)

Comment: Still doesn't work: $(x+x^2y+x^4y^2)^2$ satisfies all the conditions but the only possible way to make it weighted homogeneous is with $\deg x = \deg y =0$.

Comment: I think this is not a counter-example anymore. Note that after editing, I also imposed that the discriminant should be non-zero.
Btw: In "weighted homogeneous", I do allow negative weights. I will also add that to the post, to make things clear.